# How to make multiple asp.net ListView control use same Sorting event handler?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, listview

In a single webpage, there are four ASP.NET Webeserver ListView controls displaying data from similar collections. At present one separate ListView_Sorting event handler exists for each ListView instance. They all perform the same task. How can I write a single event handler to handle all four _Sorting events?

1. Protected Sub lvwQualified_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs) Handles lvwQualified.Sorting
2. Private Sub lvwPendDlrResln_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs) Handles lvwPendDlrResln.Sorting
3. Protected Sub lvwUnqualified_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs) Handles lvwUnqualified.Sorting
4. Protected Sub lvwPendingReview_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs) Handles lvwPendingReview.Sorting

I want to write a single handler like

Protected Sub listView_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs) Handles ListView.Sorting

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two choices:

**Specify the several events you want your Event Handler to handle**

```
Protected Sub ListView_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs) Handles lvwQualified.Sorting, lvwPendDlrResln.Sorting, lvwUnqualified.Sorting, lvwPendingReview.Sorting
    ...
End Sub
```

**Specify your Event Handler to your ListViews OnSorting methods**

```
Protected Soid ListView_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs)
    ...
End Sub
```

And then:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwQualified"
        OnSorting="ListView_Sorting"
        runat="server" />

<asp:ListView ID="lvwPendDlrResln"
        OnSorting="ListView_Sorting"
        runat="server" />

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Handles` clause allows for a list of events to handle, so you just need to add the other events separated by a comma.

You should be able to do something like:

```
Protected Sub listView_Sorting(sender As Object, e As ListViewSortEventArgs)   
Handles lvwQualified.Sorting, lvwPendDlrResln.Sorting, lvwUnqualified.Sorting, lvwPendingReview.Sorting
```